# How do I remove the indent in the output returned by CodeCogs?

Tags: compiling

This is the output when I use print code (in [CodeCogs](https://latex.codecogs.com)) in one line:

[image: Output1]

If I do the same with multiple lines, this is the output:

[image: Output2]

How do I remove the indent on the first line?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please do not forget to provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 3):

- My assumption is that the tool is *not* made for multi-line equations.
- See [here](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath) for a solution in LaTeX.

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Welcome to Overleaf --- just edit your LaTeX on the left,
% and we'll compile it for you on the right. If you open the
% 'Share' menu, you can invite other users to edit at the same
% time. See www.overleaf.com/learn for more info. Enjoy!
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{Amsmath example}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{May 2021}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\begin{align*} 
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]